# How to setup MVC style with given set of tables using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I want to implement a Veterinary Clinic Management System using Ruby on Rails.  In the picture I have what the tables would be.  I realize I would need more tables, but let's assume this is all I need.  For the Model section do I just implement a model for each given table?  For example the Customer table

```
rails generate model Customer cust_id:integer last_name:string ... treatment_id:integer
```

Do I need a model for all tables?

The next thing I want to ask, is what kind of Controllers do I implement for something like this. I'm sure it is obvious, but in case it is not, the (P) stands for primary key and the (F) stands for foreign key.

One final question, if I were to implement a multi-tier login system, can I extract any field I want for certain users regardless of what table it is?  For example maybe the office staff needs some fields in Customer table and all in Billing and all in Itemization table and all in Schedule, is that possible in rails?  I don't really need code, unless it is necessary in your answer, just a good explanation will do.

[image: Vet Clinic Management System Tables Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use many of the features in ActiveRecord (the part of Rails that handles models), you have to have a model for each table you interact with. In the model code, you'd have a `belongs_to` for each relationship on the foreign-key side and a `has_many` on the primary-key side. For example, your `Customer` model might have:

```
belongs_to :animal
belongs_to :admittance
belongs_to :discharge
belongs_to :treatment
```

And each of those four models would have a `has_many :customers`. Note that Rails assumes your primary key will be named `id` for every table and you don't have to specify it in the model-generation command.

One exception to the "one model for every table" rule is if you have a many-to-many relationship using a join table, you can leave out the model for the join table and use `has_and_belongs_to_many` on both of the models for the other tables.

You might want to ask the other questions separately, but as a quick response:

- Your controllers will depend on how you actually want people to interact with the site. You can create a model, controller, and views all together by using `rails generate scaffold`, but what it creates may not be what you actually want to have in your site.
- ActiveRecord doesn't control which fields a particular user has access to--it just returns the data in the database. As far as I know, Rails doesn't have a built-in way to do that, though there might be other gems that you can incorporate if you don't want to write the code yourself.

Comment: @Travis You generally create controllers based on how your URLs are structured. For example, `rails generate scaffold` will create a controller for a particular model: you might have a CustomersController and your users would go to `/customers/new` to create a new customer record, `/customers` to see a list of existing customer records, and some other paths. You can structure it differently, though. I'd recommend reviewing https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html if you haven't already.